# indefinite article usage with the word possible

Tags: articles

Does the word possible attract the indefinite article?
As in a possible competition.
Does it happen more often than other cases?

Comment: Why would there not be an indefinite article there?

Comment: I don't know, that's why I'm asking around. There might be other situations in life, like - the possible answer he expected and feared, stroke him.

Comment: Possible is an adjective and goes after the article and before the noun. A possible competition. A possible problem. The possible outcomes. It's just a normal adjective.